# jBPM client API not passing parameters to engine

Tags: rest, jbpm

I have jBPM 6.1.0.Final set up on WildFly 8.1. I am able to perform functions successfully.

Now I am trying to integrate the workflow engine into another application.

I have the following piece of code to test if it works or not

```
//Complete a task
        private void completeTask(String taskId) {
               restCall = url + "/rest/task/" + taskId + "/complete";

          try {
          httppost = new HttpPost(restCall);
          authorizationHeader = scheme.authenticate(credentials, httppost);
          httppost.addHeader(authorizationHeader);
          HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
          params.setParameter("map_vLobHeadComments", "Approved");
          httppost.setParams(params);
          response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

          if (response != null) {
              System.out.println("Task complete Response status line: "+ response.getStatusLine());
               if (response.getStatusLine() != null) {
                   System.out.println("Task complete Response status code: "+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
               }
          }
          } catch (ClientProtocolException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
          } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
               closeHttpClient();
          }
          }
```

Unfortunately the parameters are not getting passed to the jBPM engine.
Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Please help!!! still have he same issue

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do the rest calls yourself does not seem like a reliable way to accomplish this. You may want to look at the [Remoting API](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.1/userguide/jBPMRemoteAPI.html). I have not used the Remoting API yet, but I think this is the route you will want to take.

Answer (score 0):

Replace these lines :

```
 HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
 params.setParameter("map_vLobHeadComments", "Approved");
 httppost.setParams(params);
```

with these :

```
URIBuilder uri = new URIBuilder(httpPostCall.getURI());
uri.addParameter("map_vLobHeadComments", "Approved");
((HttpRequestBase) httppost ).setURI(uri.build());
```

This is applicable to all the POST calls to JBPM REST API.